# How to decode extrinsic at json-RPC call's data(byte code)

Tags: decode, json-rpc, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

I call json-RPC through the terminal and get the data as below.

extrinsics is raw byte, but I'm using polkadot-js(SCALE codec?) to decode it.

But I don't know which method to call.

> "block": {
> "extrinsics": [
> "0x280402000be1da78d37e01","0xd91f..(too long haha)..580"
> ],
> "header": { "digest": { ... }

@polkadot/crypto-util? @polkadot/util? Which module and which method should I use? I want input string(raw data) and get string(json or human data)
please help..